# Xcode debugger reporting Swift dictionaries as empty (po reports {})

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift, dictionary, xcode6

When I wait until Xcode 6.1.1 hits a breakpoint after this line

```
let metrics = ["leading" : 15.0, "size" : 44.0]
```

and then type `po metrics` the debugger reports (after several seconds delay) `{}`, which seems wrong. `po metrics.count` reports `2`, which is right.

Is this a feature or a bug?

**UPDATE** The problem appears when debugging on a physical device (iPhone 5), e.g. not on a simulator (e.g. iPhone 6 Plus).

Comment: I had a similar issue and debugging on the simulator also resolved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having similar issue on both simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this way?

```
let metrics:NSDictionary? = ["leading" : 15.0, "size" : 44.0]

println(metrics!)
```